# select records upto a running total (running sum)

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, running-count

I have a table similar to this in my Azure SQL Database

| itemId | qty |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 19 |
| 2 | 22 |
| 3 | 21 |
| 4 | 113 |
| 5 | 8 |
| 6 | 25 |

I have one input value X (E.g. X = 20)

Now all I want is to write a select statement to select all the itemIds of which the total qty should be >= X

So, if X=20, Item 1 and 2 should be selected, because sum(qty) will be 41 which is > 20   similarly if X = 50, then item 1, 2 and 3 should be selected, and if we do not have that much qty (X=500) then all records should be selected,

Sequence does not matter, example ,for `X=20` valid answers are

```
 1. item 1, item 2 (total sum = 41)
 2. item 2 only (total sum = 22)
 3. item 3 only (total sum = 21)
 4. item 4 only (total sum = 113)
 5. item 6 only (total sum = 25)
```

Comment: if X = 20 item 3 can be selected? only item 3? Or only as a sequence?

Comment: only item3 can also be selected, sequence does not matter

Comment: For 20, you can choose (5, 1) too, etc. A bunch of valid answers. Does it matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you could use a windowed `SUM` here to get the running total up to the *prior* row and then return rows where that total is less than your threshold:

```sql
DECLARE @Threshold int = 20;

WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT V.ItemID,
           V.Quantity,
           ISNULL(SUM(V.Quantity) OVER (ORDER BY V.ItemID
                                        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),0) AS PriorTotal
    FROM (VALUES(1,19),
                (2,22),
                (3,21),
                (4,113),
                (5,8),
                (6,25)) V(ItemID,Quantity))
SELECT ItemID,
       Quantity
FROM CTE
WHERE CTE.PriorTotal < @Threshold;
```

Comment: total sum should not be less than the threshold, it should be >= threshold

Comment: I'm not sure of your point, @AbdulMohsin , 19+22 *is* greater than (or equal to) 20. Why is 19+22 less than  20 in your opinion?

Comment: @AbdulMohsin have you tried the solution? It is calculating sum till last record for each row and display records till threshold reached. It looks correct. Please try it and accept the answer if it works for you.